# Get json object from it's position in the list

Tags: php, json

Let's say this is my json(I wont be able to change this json file):

```
{"success":true,
 "users":{
          "1036344647":{"name":"joel",    "age":18},
          "1036344365":{"name":"klant",   "age":24},
          "1036344352":{"name":"grabben", "age":23}
         }
}
```

I also have a php code that collect this json data and decodes it.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://example.com/users/json"));
```

As you can see in my json each user has a random generated id that will change everytime i collect the data from my json file. Basicly i don't know any of the user ids.


But i still want to be able to print out a users name depending on it's position in the list.

> For example: echo $data->users->[THE SECOND ID(the id with a user named "klant")]->name;

So i know this could be done easy if the json file was written as a array, but it is not.

Is there any way i can print out a object in the json depending on it's position in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a 2nd array by "throwing away" those unique IDs with `array_values()` like so:

```
$array = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
$justValues = array_values( $array["users"] );
print_r( $justValues );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => joel
            [age] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => klant
            [age] => 24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => grabben
            [age] => 23
        )

)
```

You can then access each person's data like so:

```
echo $justValues[1]["name"]; // klant
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function findUser($id)
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://example.com/users/json"));
    return isset($data[0]->users->$id) ? $data[0]->users->$id : null;
}

$user = findUser(1036344365);

var_dump($user);
```

It will output

```
object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "klant" ["age"]=> int(24) }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. JavaScript objects by design are unaware of "position" of their key-value pairs. Behind the scenes, that's what makes them powerful.

The first step is to rethink why you *need* to work with the JSON according to position.